# Jupyter - ending multiline magic command in console

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter notebook, a "cell magic" command (prefixed with two percent signs) ends at the end of the cell and is automatically invoked:

[image: %%timeit in Jupyter notebook]

But if I try the same thing in the Jupyter console, the command never ends, after any number of blank lines:

[image]

That only happens if I invoke IPython as `jupyter console`, though. If I invoke IPython directly as `ipython`, the cell magic command completes after one blank line:

[image]

For each example, the versions of Python and IPython are identical: Python 3.5.2 and IPython 6.1.0 on one machine (installed with pip), Python 3.4.5 and IPython 5.1.0 on another (installed with Conda).

Is this a bug? Or is there Jupyter default configuration somewhere for IPython that differs from IPython's own default configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug, the cell magics are suppose to ends after 2 new lines. 
The Jupyter console is way under maintained – we are not aware of many people using it, and it has plenty of issues.

Technically I *believe* the jupyter console does not use (or respect) the "is_complete" message from the protocol that should tell it wether the snippet of code should be executed or if a newline should be inserted.

You can try to open a bug report, but the fix will probably not be implemented quickly unless someone does a PR.